# How to monitor status of all threads created by executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java-threads

Is there a way to check the status of all threads created by executor service. Let's say I have 20 threads. How would I check the status of all of them?

Comment: Why do you need to know the status?

Comment: Just to check, whether it is running, crashed, etc.

Comment: But for what reason? Keep in mind that you use a thread pool, so it can handle threads for you.

Comment: I'm just curious if there was something like a getState() method to check the status

Comment: I'm not aware of any. And there is not need for one IMO. A thread pool manages threads for you, which is the point of a thread pool. A method to reflect the status defeats the purpose.

Comment: i understand your point, but i have a requirement where my threads have to report back to the main thread about their status after a certain amount of time. do you know if i could use future in this case

Comment: @akuzminykh, the thread pool manages threads _for_ you, but unless this is the `commonPool` or some pool provided by a framework, **you** manage the thread pool.

Comment: @acelent I'm not sure how this addresses my statement. Could you say in other words?

Comment: @akuzminykh, you said _"A method to reflect the status defeats the purpose."_ What's wrong with having threads report back to the thread pool user/owner? If it's your thread pool, you can do whatever you want or need. That's what some HTTP and message queuing frameworks do. The framework, and not the thread pool, is actually deciding to e.g. queue requests/messages or respond with service unavailable or whatever, based on that reporting/statistics. Usually, they just wrap the execution of each `Runnable` or provide a custom `ThreadFactory`.

Comment: @acelent It's not wrong per se, but such a method just shouldn't be there inherently. And this is why there *is* no direct and simple `getState()` method for thread pools. I've just explained why that is.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to monitor status of all threads in thread pool,you can try create your ThreadFactory like the below code:

```
public class SelfThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private Map<Long, Thread> stateMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        stateMap.put(thread.getId(), thread);
        return thread;
    }

    public Map<Long, Thread> getStateMap() {
        return stateMap;
    }
}
```

Use getStateMap() method you can get all thread created by this ThreadFactory,then you can get state of thread.

Comment: Bear in mind that `@NotNull` is not part of Java SE.

Comment: @VGR thanks,`@NotNull` is add by my idea,i have modify  the code。

Comment: Beware this approach will break CachedThreadPool as all threads will have hard reference now and will not be garbage collected!

Answer (score 1):

You may extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` and use its methods `beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)` and `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` to monitor the status of the tasks/threads.

You can find an example implementation [in this article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-tips-creating-a-monitoring-friendly-executors)